# Getting the process name for a given Port in Java on Ubuntu-Linux?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I want to get the process name for the given PORT ID in Java, Ubuntu. I found samples how to do it in windows(tasklist in RunTime). But I need to know this in Linux.

Comment: did you mean process id?

Comment: not the process id. I want to know the process name for my given port.

Comment: @Débora I think you just changed the essence of your whole question which previously was "how do I get the process name given the PID?".

Comment: This is unclear - you refer to tasklist on Windows: it shows the process name and PID (= ***process*** id) but does not show what ports are used by the process.

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to list the application which listens to a certain **port**, you can use the unix command `lsof` in combination with `awk`:

```
lsof -i :80 | awk '{print $1}'
```

This will list you i.e. the commandname from the process which listens to port 80.

In your javacode you have write following:

```
int port = 80;
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("lsof -i :" + port + " | awk '{print $1}'");

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

---

Note that if you want to get a process name based on a process id (PID), you can use this instead:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -ef | awk '{if($2==\"" + pid + "\") print $8}'");
```

Comment: your initial answer was interesting and it is still not clear what the op wants so I've added the code for PID as a side note - hope you don't mind.

Comment: @chresse. I highly appreciate your support. This is what I exactly looked for. and once again, I thank you so much.

Comment: @assylias: of course i've no problem - you are very welcome. As long it helps other people :)

Comment: @Débora: I am happy if you can use it :)

Comment: @chresse : Sure. I did small changes and, it worked. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 2):

The `/proc` file system helps. `/proc/$PID/exe` is a symbolic link to the executable corresponding to the process ID. Obviously, you can simply read that file from Java.

Edit: Before, you asked for "process ID", now it is about a TCP/IP port... that renders my answer useless.

Comment: Thanks. But would you mind let me know with sample code please in Java ?